# Magnets quantum locking/levitating

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, levitation

How does cooling a magnet allow it to quantum lock/levitate? I have seen it in videos but do not know how it works.

Comment: This is also called [flux pinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_pinning).

Comment: Meissner effect

Comment: A superconductor upon reaching critical temperature usually (very low) will become a perfect diamagnet meaning they exclude all magnetic flux from the superconductor. Hence when you place a permanent magnet onto it surface, the magnetic field lines cannot penetrate the surface and have to lift it up so the lines can reach the other pole.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15855/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48421/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Note: Not all of the flux lines are blocked from entering the superconductor. There are very few small flux lines called fluxons that flow through the superconductor.